# SendKey to a game in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, udp, sendkeys

Quick question, I have a WinForm vb.net project that sends keystroke using the SendKey method based on a received UDP message. My code works like charm when using Notepad or something like that but, the ultimate goal of my app is to send those commands to a game (Elite Dangerous in this case) but it does not work... The game never receives the keystroke.
Any idea why? The game is the focused application because I'm playing it, if I switch to my app I see the UDP message is received and the command is sent, if I focus Notepad, it works but not with the game :(

Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Shared listenPort As Integer
    Private Shared HostIP As IPAddress
    Public CheckResult As Boolean = False
    Public KeystrokeMessage As String = ""
    Public cpt As Integer = 0
    Dim p() As Process

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Disable the Start button until a local IP is selected
        StartStopBtn.Enabled = False

        ' ####################################
        ' ## Get list of local IP addresses ##
        ' ####################################
        Dim hostname As String
        'get host name
        hostname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        'get a list of IP addresses for the give host name
        Dim hostentry As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)
        'List all IP used on the PC in the ComboBox
        For Each ip As System.Net.IPAddress In hostentry.AddressList
            If ip.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(ip.ToString())
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' If an IP address is selected, the Start button is enabled
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem <> "- Please select -" Then
            StartStopBtn.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartStopBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartStopBtn.Click
        Select Case StartStopBtn.Text
            Case "Start Listening"
                ' Update the interface
                StartStopBtn.Text = "Stop Listening"
                ComboBox1.Enabled = False
                UDPTextBox.Enabled = False
                ' Start listening to UDP messages
                listenPort = CInt(UDPTextBox.Text)
                If Not (ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Any") Then
                    Try
                        HostIP = IPAddress.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("error")
                    End Try
                End If

                If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = True Then
                    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
                End If

            Case "Stop Listening"
                ' Update the interface
                StartStopBtn.Text = "Start Listening"
                ComboBox1.Enabled = True
                UDPTextBox.Enabled = True
                ' Stop listening to UDP messages
                BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
                BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        Dim done As Boolean = False
        Dim listener As New UdpClient(listenPort)
        Dim groupEP As New IPEndPoint(HostIP, listenPort)
        Dim mystring As String

        Try
            While Not done
                If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                    listener.Close()
                    Exit While
                Else
                    If (listener.Available > 0) Then
                        Dim bytes As Byte() = listener.Receive(groupEP)
                        KeystrokeMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                        mystring = "From " & groupEP.ToString() & " : " & KeystrokeMessage
                        worker.ReportProgress(0, mystring)
                    End If
                End If
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            listener.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = False) Then
            MessageTextBox.Text = (e.UserState.ToString)
            SendKeystroke()
        End If
        Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendKeystroke()
        ' Check the content of the received UDP message
        Select Case KeystrokeMessage.Substring(0, 8)
            ' If the message starts by "SendKey." then remote the header and send the rest of the message
            ' ex: if the message is "SendKey.A" the process will send A 
            Case "SendKey."
                SendKeys.SendWait(KeystrokeMessage.Substring(8))
            ' If not, just display the message in the Textbox with the mention "Invalid command" and do nothing else
            Case Else
                MessageTextBox.Text = MessageTextBox.Text & " (Invalid command!)"
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Apparently it uses DirectX keystrokes: [help sending keystrokes to elite dangerous game](http://www.eventghost.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6374).

Comment: I see... Not that easy then :(  Anyone knows how to send DX Keystrokes?